# json not working with ajax but working fine when used directly

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using json to read records. It works perfectly fine if I use it inside the javascript like this

```
var events=[{eventId:"1", event_name:"wedding"},{eventId:"2", event_name:"interview"}]
```

then loop it to read records

```
for(var events_count=0;events_count<events.length;events_count++)
{
//read records and works perfectly fine
}
```

but when I am doing the same using ajax, it is not working. I have even put the text

```
{eventId:"1", event_name:"wedding"},{eventId:"2", event_name:"interview"}
```

in the ajax called(ajax-get-events.php) page, It doesn't go inside the loop

```
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        //got data in same format as above in xmlhttp.responseText and used eval to parse it

         events = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

        //I have tried to alert(events) and it shows [object object]

           for(var events_count=0;events_count<events.length;events_count++)
            {
                //loop doesn't work at all

            }
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-get-events.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Please tell me what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: If your `responseText` is JSON, why are you using `eval()` rather than `JSON.parse()` to parse it? Also, can you include the response text that's returned from the AJAX request, please?

Comment: 1) don't eval. There are better alternatives
2) make a console.log of the responseText

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. [test it](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: I have converted it to valid json by making it[
    {
        "eventId": "1",
        "event_name": "wedding"
    },
    {
        "eventId": "2",
        "event_name": "interview"
    }
]  but still not working and it was working fine in the javascript part as I told you so thats should not be problem related to valid json

Comment: You told yourself that the JavaScript part is fine, so the problem must be on the JSON side. Don't you think?

Comment: @greut The fact that they've said the JavaScript part is fine doesn't automatically mean that the JavaScript part **is** fine - there are obvious issues with the JavaScript. Most notably, using `eval()` and wrapping the string containing the JSON in parentheses at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not parsed as a JSON array, but as one object (the second one):

```
{eventId:"1", event_name:"wedding"},{eventId:"2", event_name:"interview"}
```

But this should be parsed (read eval'd) as a correct array:

```
[{"eventId":"1", "event_name":"wedding"},{"eventId":"2", "event_name":"interview"}]
```

Since you're using PHP, use `json_encode` to generate your JSON output, it'll be correct JSON.

Comment: I have used first json_encode intially with the database operation but It was not working though it was sending same output[{"eventId":"1", "event_name":"wedding"},{"eventId":"2", "event_name":"interview"}] that's why I have tried to put simple json text

Comment: alert/console.log it, you should be able to see an Array.